# How would I implement this code into my Wordpress site using WPbakery

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have this codepen which is an altered version of the parallax code from firewatch.

https://codepen.io/Lancewalker/pen/EGqVZe

```js
function castParallax() {

 var opThresh = 350;
 var opFactor = 750;

 window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event){

  var top = this.pageYOffset;

  var layers = document.getElementsByClassName("parallax");
  var layer, speed, yPos;
  for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
   layer = layers[i];
   speed = layer.getAttribute('data-speed');
   var yPos = -(top * speed / 100);
   layer.setAttribute('style', 'transform: translate3d(0px, ' + yPos + 'px, 0px)');

  }
 });
}

document.body.onload = castParallax();
```

```css
/* PARALLAX */

.body {
  margin: -5px;
}

.keyart, .keyart_layer {
 height: 1000px;
}

#parallax {
 display: block;
}

.keyart {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
}

.keyart_layer {
 background-position: bottom center;
 background-size: auto 1038px;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}
.keyart_layer.parallax {
 position: fixed;
}
 #keyart-0 {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/1faPCRE.png");
  background-color: #ffaf1b;
 }
 #keyart-1 {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/EKhFCWk.png");
 }
 #keyart-2 {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/o4PVCnk.png");
 }
 #keyart-3 {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/bnVtpuR.png");
 }
 #keyart-4 {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/bnVtpuR.png");
 }
 #keyart-5 {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/R5jRdBC.png");
 }
 #keyart-6 {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/ORZm7M7.png");
 }
 #keyart-7 {
  background-image: url("");
 }
 #keyart-8 {
  background-image: url("");
 }
 #keyart-scrim {
  background-color: #ffaf00;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="keyart" id="parallax">
  <div class="keyart_layer parallax" id="keyart-0" data-speed="2"></div>  <!-- 00.0 -->
  <div class="keyart_layer parallax" id="keyart-1" data-speed="5"></div> <!-- 12.5 -->
  <div class="keyart_layer parallax" id="keyart-2" data-speed="11"></div>  <!-- 25.0 -->
  <div class="keyart_layer parallax" id="keyart-3" data-speed="16"></div> <!-- 37.5 -->
  <div class="keyart_layer parallax" id="keyart-4" data-speed="26"></div>  <!-- 50.0 -->
  <div class="keyart_layer parallax" id="keyart-5" data-speed="36"></div> <!-- 62.5 -->
  <div class="keyart_layer parallax" id="keyart-6" data-speed="49"></div>  <!-- 75.0 -->
  <div class="keyart_layer" id="keyart-scrim"></div>
  <div class="keyart_layer parallax" id="keyart-7" data-speed="69"></div>  <!-- 87.5 -->
  <div class="keyart_layer" id="keyart-8" data-speed="100"></div>  <!-- 100. -->
</div>
```

My goal is to have this as the header/intro image to my site.

I can easily implement this when a site is using simple html / css / JS, for instance I was able to quickly make it work on a friend's shopify site in just a minute or two.

With WPBakery though, the custom HTML element doesn't output the HTML / CSS in a way that overrides the WPBakery configs, so every single element I am creating with WPBakery has a base class that overrides things like width, height, padding, margins, etc based on whatever I choose in the configs. This is causing issues and my element is showing up as a blank space in the web page.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make this code work. I don't really know any PHP whatsoever, but am pretty good at front end development at this point. The more I work with CMS that let's me easily make changes in html / css / js the more wordpress is causing problems for me.

I installed a plugin that lets me add custom JS and CSS/SCSS, implemented the code there and then used the HTML output in the "custom html" element in WPBakery but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

At this point I'm comfortable enough to code my entire site just using an IDE and html / css / js.. I wish there was an easy way to add elements to wordpress easily that I create (is there?) without WPBakery causing so much difficulty.

Comment: Have you been able to identify the template files WPBakery uses? You might need to override some of them to achieve your desired outcome.

Comment: yeah its not too difficult to get into the plugin folder and change the css stylesheet but the issue is that I don't want to change the base class of whatever WPBakery applies to normal elements because most of the time it's totally fine.

Comment: Templates are php files, not stylesheets. I'm not suggesting you modify them from the plugin's folder, those will be overridden by the next update. What you can do is copy the template to your theme's folder (assuming you're using a child theme, which is a must for any theme modification) and then add the markup there. Not the best solution, I know, but gets the job done. If you're comfortable with CSS,  you're much better off using a good starter theme like Underscores (that you can hack completely without the need of creating a child theme), use ACF for content, and styling it your own.